# haskell-stack won't install ghc

Tags: haskell-stack

Trying to do stack setup to install stack ghc on Mint 18, - keep getting configure error:

```
checking for path to top of build tree... /home/frank/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2
Build platform inferred as: x86_64-unknown-linux
Host platform inferred as: x86_64-unknown-linux
Target platform inferred as: x86_64-unknown-linux
GHC build  : x86_64-unknown-linux
GHC host   : x86_64-unknown-linux
GHC target : x86_64-unknown-linux
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gsed... sed
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking for llc-3.7... no
checking for llc... no
checking for opt-3.7... no
checking for opt... no
checking for ld... /usr/bin/ld
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in /home/frank/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2.temp/ghc-8.0.2:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this problem was because I did not have a C compiler installed on my machine.
I solved it by using the command-
sudo apt-get install g++